# Lidgren message receiving error

Tags: c#, xna, lidgren

I'm working on an xna networked game with lidgren and I can get the client and server to connect, but whenever the client receives a message in the DiscoveryRequest case I get the IndexOutOfRangeException error.

Code for recieving messages in client:

```
while ((incMsg = client.ReadMessage()) != null)
        {
            switch (incMsg.MessageType)
            {
                case NetIncomingMessageType.Data:
                    Console.WriteLine("recieved message");
                    break;

                case NetIncomingMessageType.DiscoveryRequest:
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected",incMsg.ReadString());
                    client.Connect(incMsg.SenderEndpoint);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Unhandled type: " + incMsg.MessageType);
                    break;
            }
            client.Recycle(incMsg);
        }
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error and what is the stack trace?

Comment: I get the error on Console.WriteLine("Connected",incMsg.ReadString());

Answer (score 1):

Way old question, but for posterity: the DiscoveryRequest does not contain any payload, there is no string to read. It's detailed here: https://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/wiki/Discovery